# How to write a Junit test for a morse code binary tree

Tags: java, swing, junit

I have built a code tree in a Tree class and it is called using a java swing gui. The nodes were implemented like this:

```
@Override
public void addChild(Node<treeNode> child) {
    children.add(child);       
}

@Override
public void addChild(int i) {
    children.add(i);    
}

Node<String> H = new NodeImplement<String>("H", S, "left");
S.addChild(H);
```

The code responds to each left and right mouse-click eg. I can print SOS to the screen but how do I go about writing a test for SOS? Do I assert "left", "left", "left" = 'S' and so on?

Comment: Not nearly enough info here.  How do you "print SOS to the screen"?  If you have a method that returns the `String` "SOS", you can test that.  If not, it might be a good idea to add one.  A recursive method (if that's what you have) that just outputs a character when it thinks it should is too inflexible, and would be the wrong approach in a real-world program.

Comment: @ajb Thanks for reply, I did not use a String method as you suggested, I used the e.isMetaDown() function in the gui class and then appended that node to the screen - not a real world scenario so I am not really concerned about my approach in this instance, any other insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implementation to test the letter has been added to the tree works

```
@Test
public void testLetterA() {

    String expected = "A";
    MorseNode<String> actual = p.addLetterToTree();
    assertEquals(p.constructTree(), actual);
}
```